# Get current ASP.NET Trust Level programmatically

Tags: asp.net

Is there an API to get the current ASP.NET Trust Level?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [dmitryr's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20100409002741/http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2007/01/23/finding-out-the-current-trust-level-in-asp-net.aspx):

```
AspNetHostingPermissionLevel GetCurrentTrustLevel() {
foreach (AspNetHostingPermissionLevel trustLevel in
        new AspNetHostingPermissionLevel [] {
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted,
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.High,
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium,
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low,
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal 
        } ) {
    try {
        new AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand();
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException ) {
        continue;
    }

    return trustLevel;
 }

 return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code get current ASP.NET Trust Level programmatically using the official configuration API:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;

...

var trust = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/trust") as TrustSection;
return trust.Level;
```

Comment: It was so obvious, sorry.