# How do I tell programatically if I am running under Medium Trust?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# how do I tell if my assembly is running under medium trust in asp.net?  Is there something similar to Debugger.IsAttached for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064274/get-current-asp-net-trust-level-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

[Get current ASP.NET Trust Level programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064274/get-current-asp-net-trust-level-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

From dmitryr's blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2007/01/23/finding-out-the-current-trust-level-in-asp-net.aspx):

```
public static AspNetHostingPermissionLevel GetTrustLevel()
{
    foreach (AspNetHostingPermissionLevel trustLevel in new AspNetHostingPermissionLevel[]
                                                            {
                                                                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted,
                                                                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.High,
                                                                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium,
                                                                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low,
                                                                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal
                                                            })
    {
        try
        {
            new AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand();
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
        {
            continue;
        }

        return trustLevel;
    }

    return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this slightly shorter version

```
public AspNetHostingPermissionLevel GetCurrentTrustLevel()
{
    foreach (AspNetHostingPermissionLevel trustLevel in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AspNetHostingPermissionLevel)))
    {
        try
        {
            new AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand();
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
        {
            continue;
        }
        return trustLevel;
    }
    return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None;
}
```