# How to translate this C# code to detect the current Trust Level for ASP.NET Application into VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I found this code:

```cs
AspNetHostingPermissionLevel GetCurrentTrustLevel() {
    foreach (AspNetHostingPermissionLevel trustLevel in
            new AspNetHostingPermissionLevel [] {
                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted,
                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.High,
                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium,
                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low,
                AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal 
            } )
    {
        try {
            new AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand();
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException ) {
            continue;
        }

        return trustLevel;
    }

    return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None;
}
```

from [Get current ASP.NET Trust Level programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064274/get-current-asp-net-trust-level-programmatically/4774231#4774231), but this is C#, and I would like to have it for VB.NET. 
Any chance of someone expert in both VB.NET and C# that can translate this to VB code?

I tried myself and got the following VB.NET code but it generates an error inside my VWD:

```vb
Private Function GetCurrentTrustLevel() As AspNetHostingPermissionLevel

    For Each trustLevel As AspNetHostingPermissionLevel In New _
        AspNetHostingPermissionLevel() { _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.High, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal _
        }

            Try
                New AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand()
            Catch generatedExceptionName As System.Security.SecurityException
                Continue Try
            End Try

            Return trustLevel
        Next

        Return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None
    End Function
```

These parts seems to be wrong:

```vb
New AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand()
```

and

```vb
Continue Try
```

Obviously, need to be handled by someone fluent in both C# and VB.NET and can spot the errors in VB.NET

Thanks

Lars

Comment: Try to load it up in Reflector, and choose to display it in VB.Net. Usually works. http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will look into that next time I come across a similar C# vs VB.NET problem.
Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
Private Function GetCurrentTrustLevel() As AspNetHostingPermissionLevel

    For Each trustLevel As AspNetHostingPermissionLevel In New _
        AspNetHostingPermissionLevel() { _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.High, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low, _
            AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal _
        }

            Try
                Dim HostedPermission As AspNetHostingPermission = _
                    New AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel)
                HostedPermission.Demand()
            Catch generatedExceptionName As System.Security.SecurityException
                Continue For
            End Try

            Return trustLevel
        Next

        Return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None
    End Function
```

I am no VB.Net expert, but the following is what I did to get it to work:

1. `Continue For` rather than `Continue Try`
2. Needed to declare a variable of type `AspNetHostingPermission` and initialize it, then call the `Demand` method.

Comment: But you are a VB.Net Expert :-)
You solved it!
Excellent! Thank you!
Lars

Comment: @lars happy to be of service :)