# How to set trust level for complete asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, medium-trust

I need to set the trust level of a sample asp.net web application so that my hosting provider can support it. I changed the trust level in the web.config but that doesn't seem to work. I have been advised to change it for the entire application. How can I do that?

Comment: Just contact your hosting provider and ask them to give full permission for you.

Answer (score 0):

See this post:
[Get current ASP.NET Trust Level programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064274/get-current-asp-net-trust-level-programmatically)

If you want to change the trust level you need to modify the web.config. Are you sure that you do it in the right way? Try to code in the post above to get the current trust level at run-time, and verify that it's Full Trust.